# UITableView Repeats First Cell On Occasion

Tags: ios, uitableview

My Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
if(indexPath.section == 0){
    homeDir = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", homeDir, @"Documents"];
}else{
    homeDir = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", homeDir, @"Documents/Archived"];
}
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:homeDir error:nil];

dirContents = [[dirContents reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.3; //seconds
[cell addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

int i = 0;
NSString *filename;
if([dirContents count] > 0){
    filename = [[dirContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
    while(![[filename substringFromIndex: [filename length] - 3] isEqualToString:@"pdf"]){
        i ++;
        filename = [[dirContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + i] lastPathComponent];
    }
}else{
     filename = @" ";
}


cell.textLabel.text = filename;

return cell;
```

}

The issue I am having is that, on occasion, only the first cell returns repeatedly. If an array reads "Red, Blue, Green, Yellow" it appears as:

Red

Red

Red

Red

This happens only on occasion. Sometimes when refreshing the table, it displays correctly, only to later revert back to the incorrect display. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain about your coding?

Comment: You are creating the datasource for the table on every single cell creation. Try moving the `dirContents` init outside of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, like in `viewDidLoad`. Also, have you tried posting NSLogs throughout your code while the cell is being created? My guess is that the cell itself isn't being repeated, but your array is not returning the correct value, so it's setting the `cell.textLabel.text` to "Red" every time a new cell is created.

Comment: At one point you have `indexPath.row` for your fetch, then later you use `indexPath.row + 1`. You should probably fix that, though I don't know that it would cause the bug you're describing.

Comment: You are also adding a gesture every time, you only want to do that if its a new cell. Sorry not the real issue but worth looking into

Comment: How are you determining how many rows are in the table, show the code you have for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

Comment: I should mention that the tableview has to update dynamically. The app downloads files and after each file downloaded. I want that new file to be displayed each time. I guess I should put the dirContents in something that's only called once, like the number of sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a comment above, but I'm going to try for an answer because I suspect this will fix your problem, if not just to show what is actually happening here.

A UITableView should have a datasource. In your original code you are creating this datasource (the array `dirContents`) every time the table view creates a new cell. It looks like your datasource is static, so you can create this outside of the UITableViewDataSource delegate method, and place it somewhere such as the `viewDidLoad` method. It's only an assumption of mine that this array is not being created in time to access the elements for your cell.

You can then confirm that your cell is grabbing the correct index from this array with a NSLog right before `cell.textLabel.text = filename;`.

Hopefully this helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Marcel, you have to re-architect your code, you have put the code which gets file names from the directory in viewDidLoad and save these names in a global array and then in cellForRowAtIndex make use of this array. 
For refreshing of tableView on each download, just reload uitableview as file is completely donwloaded. Hope it Helps!

Comment: Will viewDidLoad get called again on table refresh?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called only once, You have to reload tableView using [myTableView reloadData]; at completion of download.

Comment: That's the problem. If I download a new file and use reloadData (which is currently what I am doing) then dirContents doesn't get reloaded, which means the new file won't show up in the table.